# exporting animated model to unity 5 totally deform the mesh

Tags: export, rigging, import, unity

I am trying to import a model in unity from blender. But using FBX is a total disaster, collada looks "better", at least I can recognize the arms and legs.
This is the link for the original blend file:
https://copy.com/DHMZ4ACjSoyYroAm
 [image]

hopefully someone can give me a clue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found I had better luck using the FBX 6.1 ASCII settings when exporting to Unity.  Are you animating using bones? I never had any luck importing shape key animations into Unity.

[image]

These are the settings I used and had the most success.

Comment: you are awesome!!! the corrective shapekeys used to fix deformation inside blender make the problem, i deleted all but the "basis" and used the export setting you recommended, it works thanks!!!

Comment: Glad I could help!  I actually just switched back to .FBX.  Before I was loading the .blend files into Unity.  I just found out that Unity just opens the .blend file up in the background and converts it to a .FBX